# How to display pictures in swagger-ui/index.html?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui

I have problem with display pictures in swagger-ui/index.html. I have thit screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, there is no svg on top and no icon in search bar. My security configuration in Spring boot is :

```
permission:
  # list of url for permit all
  optionMethodPermitAll:
    - "/graphql"
    - "/auth/token"
    - "/auth/refresh"
    - "/actuator/*"
    - "/api/*"

  permitAll:
    - "/actuator/*"
    - "/auth/token"
    - "/auth/refresh"
    - "/v2/api-docs"
    - "/webjars/**"
    - "/swagger*/**"
    - "/favicon.ico"
    - "/swagger-resources/**"
    - "/webjars/**"
```

I use this configuration in pom.xml:

```
       <springfox.swagger.version>3.0.0</springfox.swagger.version>
   <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
           <version>${springfox.swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

But swagger dont display icon in search bar and header svg. Im little bit stuck with it. Thank you for help

Here I have log of request & responses:

```
13:02:05.397 [main] [] INFO  o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain - Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@5dd62f07, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@6e669b5c, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@304cad3a, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1e9e4468, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@2c6553c6, com.dhl.security.aaa.adapter.configuration.AuthenticationFilter@3db3668, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@455cb6d9, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@7c35d7d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@125c03d3, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@54c697c, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@4f4b7a2e, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@14aa2123]
13:02:07.236 [main] [] INFO  o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
13:02:08.180 [main] [] INFO  com.dhl.order.OrdersApplication - Started OrdersApplication in 14.131 seconds (JVM running for 16.54)
13:02:16.653 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] [] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
13:02:16.654 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] [] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
13:02:16.656 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] [] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 2 ms
13:02:16.676 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] [] DEBUG c.d.s.a.a.mdc.RequestResponseMDC - Request processing started, distribute_trace_id has been generated; old ID: 'null', new ID: 'fd5000eb996b4ab4a487c26b01a4357a'; httpMethod=GET, URI=/swagger-ui/index.html
13:02:16.699 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] [fd5000eb996b4ab4a487c26b01a4357a] INFO  c.d.s.a.a.c.AuthenticationFilter - Request skipped from JWT verification; url=/swagger-ui/index.html
13:02:16.777 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] [fd5000eb996b4ab4a487c26b01a4357a] INFO  c.d.s.a.a.c.AAACommonRequestFilter - Request processing finished; httpStatus=304, duration=85ms, httpMethod=GET, URI=/swagger-ui/index.html, httpParams=null, requestData=[]
13:02:17.004 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] [] DEBUG c.d.s.a.a.mdc.RequestResponseMDC - Request processing started, distribute_trace_id has been generated; old ID: 'null', new ID: '3bc4a6f564fa4f658524b69ea7887ed3'; httpMethod=GET, URI=/swagger-resources/configuration/ui
13:02:17.005 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] [3bc4a6f564fa4f658524b69ea7887ed3] INFO  c.d.s.a.a.c.AuthenticationFilter - Request skipped from JWT verification; url=/swagger-resources/configuration/ui
13:02:17.100 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] [3bc4a6f564fa4f658524b69ea7887ed3] INFO  c.d.s.a.a.c.AAACommonRequestFilter - Request processing finished; httpStatus=200, duration=95ms, httpMethod=GET, URI=/swagger-resources/configuration/ui, httpParams=null, requestData=[]
13:02:17.108 [http-nio-8081-exec-4] [] DEBUG c.d.s.a.a.mdc.RequestResponseMDC - Request processing started, distribute_trace_id has been generated; old ID: 'null', new ID: '6b368c33db87483bb89c4ba683108232'; httpMethod=GET, URI=/swagger-resources/configuration/security
13:02:17.109 [http-nio-8081-exec-4] [6b368c33db87483bb89c4ba683108232] INFO  c.d.s.a.a.c.AuthenticationFilter - Request skipped from JWT verification; url=/swagger-resources/configuration/security
13:02:17.117 [http-nio-8081-exec-4] [6b368c33db87483bb89c4ba683108232] INFO  c.d.s.a.a.c.AAACommonRequestFilter - Request processing finished; httpStatus=200, duration=8ms, httpMethod=GET, URI=/swagger-resources/configuration/security, httpParams=null, requestData=[]
13:02:17.127 [http-nio-8081-exec-5] [] DEBUG c.d.s.a.a.mdc.RequestResponseMDC - Request processing started, distribute_trace_id has been generated; old ID: 'null', new ID: '86e2d72af6bb4187bf4412d099839bc1'; httpMethod=GET, URI=/swagger-resources
13:02:17.128 [http-nio-8081-exec-5] [86e2d72af6bb4187bf4412d099839bc1] INFO  c.d.s.a.a.c.AuthenticationFilter - Request skipped from JWT verification; url=/swagger-resources
13:02:17.136 [http-nio-8081-exec-5] [86e2d72af6bb4187bf4412d099839bc1] INFO  c.d.s.a.a.c.AAACommonRequestFilter - Request processing finished; httpStatus=200, duration=8ms, httpMethod=GET, URI=/swagger-resources, httpParams=null, requestData=[]
13:02:17.163 [http-nio-8081-exec-6] [] DEBUG c.d.s.a.a.mdc.RequestResponseMDC - Request processing started, distribute_trace_id has been generated; old ID: 'null', new ID: '240c57bbbaba436bb55a42054badec5b'; httpMethod=GET, URI=/v2/api-docs
13:02:17.166 [http-nio-8081-exec-6] [240c57bbbaba436bb55a42054badec5b] INFO  c.d.s.a.a.c.AuthenticationFilter - Request skipped from JWT verification; url=/v2/api-docs
13:02:17.345 [http-nio-8081-exec-6] [240c57bbbaba436bb55a42054badec5b] INFO  c.d.s.a.a.c.AAACommonRequestFilter - Request processing finished; httpStatus=200, duration=180ms, httpMethod=GET, URI=/v2/api-docs, httpParams=null, requestData=[]
```

Comment: what is the error code for the (missing) images? (404/403/401??) what is their path? (404: are they available? 401/403: does path comply with "allow list"?...;)